# Someone can explain this strange behavior?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have javascript function called every 30 seconds:

```
function getOutput() {
sleep(30000);
setInterval(function(){
 getRequest(
      'prova1.php', // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return true;
 },30000);
```

The prova1.php file execute a command that open two page containing text in json format and save them in the local repository, the pages with json files are updated by a c++ program approximately every 20 sec:

```
<?php

  exec(" wget http://127.0.0.1:8082/Canvases/Fe0_Cbc0_Calibration/root.json -O provami1.json");
   exec(" wget http://127.0.0.1:8082/Canvases/Fe0_Cbc1_Calibration/root.json -O provami2.json");

?>
```

The strange thing that happends is that when I look the execution of the code in first moment the script save the files provami1.json and provami2.json with size of x kbyte, but after a second provami2.json become 0 and is empty. If is the last run, and the c++ program terminates , both file are with the right data. I really can't understand why it happends. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Where is `c++` here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the fact that AJAX is async so you will return true before having anykind of response from the request.

**try to debug this way:**

```
function getOutput() {
sleep(30000);
setInterval(function(){
 getRequest(
      'prova1.php', // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
      // Also debug here the response from the request.
  );
 console.log('2');
  return true;
 },30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check user have write permission or not and try to use wget with append option i.e. wget -o logfile URL -a.
I think if you are using wget for just retrieving the data then PHP have option to do that, you can use CURL or file_get_content for just get the data and write into a file. Afterwards your c++ prog will do the rest. Hope this will help you